# Split list on unique batches

Tags: java, algorithm

We have list of strings elements. For example ["A","B","B","A","K","B"].  Our program must split this list on next batches [["A","B","K"], ["B","A"], ["B"]].  All butches must contain only unique elements, number of batches must be minimal and complexity of algorithm must be linear O(n).

Comment: sounds like a homework... what did you try so far? where is the problem?

Comment: Truely homework, sorry we can't help :D Make a try, produce an error, post your code here and ask for that particular error ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally don't answer when the questions looks like a homework, which I think it is. But well... here is a **nice and simple solution** using `List`, `Set` and `Recursion`. (If you care about the order, then replace `HashSet` with `LinkedHashSet`)

---

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringBatches {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] ss = {"A","B","B","A","K","B", "A"};

        List<Set<String>> l = new ArrayList<Set<String>>();
        for (String s : ss) {
            putInUniqueSet(l, 0, s);
        }
        System.out.println( l );
    }

    public static boolean putInUniqueSet( List<Set<String>> l, int idx, String s ) {
        if( l.size() <= idx )
            l.add(new HashSet<String>());
        return !l.get(idx).add(s) ? putInUniqueSet(l, idx+1, s) : true;
    }
}
```

---

**Output**:

```
[[A, B, K], [A, B], [A, B]]
```

Comment: Could you explain the return statement? Never seen anything like that :D

Comment: well, the `add(s)` will return `true` if `set` doesnt contain the `s` already. Which means if `s` is new in the set, then fine. Otherwise when `s` exists then try to put the `s` in the next existing `set` using recursion. Until `s` finds a `set` which doesnt contain `s`... if you mean the usage of `?` and `:` its kind of a if else stmnt, a ternary operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Answer (score 0):

Try to use list and set. Your Set doesn't allow dupllicate values and List allows. So you might want to iterate over all elements and while adding to set check if length is changed and if length is not changed means it's duplicate and add it to List. So your next set will be the list. and keep doing the same unless your list size comes to zero. it's just a hint hope this helps.

Happy Learning :)

Comment: What do you mean by set?

Comment: Set is a data structure in java which doesn't allow duplicate value

Answer (score 0):

This one should work. (And has been tested)

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> batches = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

    arr.add("A");
    arr.add("B");
    arr.add("B");
    arr.add("A");
    arr.add("K");
    arr.add("B");
    arr.add("A");

    batches.add(new ArrayList<String>());

    int id = 0, arrID = 0;

    while(arrID < arr.size())
    {
        if(batches.get(id).contains(arr.get(arrID)))
        {
            id ++;
            if(id+1 > batches.size())
                batches.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        }
        else
        {
            batches.get(id).add(arr.get(arrID));
            arrID ++;
            id = 0;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Results: ");
    for(int i=0; i<batches.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Batch "+i);
        for(int x=0; x<batches.get(i).size(); x++)
            System.out.println(batches.get(i).get(x));
    }
```

Comment: Fixed something try it now.

Comment: too slow solution)

Comment: What do you mean? I can optimise it :)

Comment: U have 3 nested loops and it giveO(n^3) complexity

Comment: @Faorest23 The loops don't really run fully, if you analyse the code you'll get it.

Comment: @MrSimpleMind Why is my solution wrong? can you explain because I tested it.

Comment: @MrSimpleMind it outputs: [["A","B","K"], ["B","A"], ["B", "A"]].

Comment: solution with set not bad but we have near O(n^2) complexity.

Comment: @Faorest23 Did that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do a list of lists

eg

package dummy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BatchIt {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<String>> batches = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    List<String> firstBatch = new ArrayList<String>();
    batches.add(firstBatch);
    for (String input : args) {
        boolean inputAdded = false;
        for (List<String> batch : batches) {
            if(!batch.contains(input)){
                batch.add(input);
                inputAdded = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!inputAdded){
            List<String> nextBatch = new ArrayList<String>();
            nextBatch.add(input);
            batches.add(nextBatch);
        }
    }
    System.out.print(batches);
}
```

}